# What is the meaning of public="storage" in the HTML doctype?

Tags: html

The `PUBLIC` attribute in the `doctype` [means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration#Syntax) that the document is not private and can be accessed by the general public.

Is there a special meaning to the `"storage"` value associated with it in this example?
Also, does it matter if PUBLIC is all uppercase or all lowercase?

```
<!doctype html public="storage">
```

I came across it in the `index.html` of this repo - https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial.

Comment: Doesn't pass W3 validation

Comment: I suspect this falls under the category of "None of the tools we use care about what comes after the 'html' bit of the Doctype, let's just shove our extendo-crap in there"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Someone else posted this in an answer but deleted it for some reason. It is apparently a joke by the author of that document — who, in a [comment on a GitHub issue](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/3141#issuecomment-191643825), links to a number of other instances of this oddity within the same project. As Quentin comments,

> I suspect this falls under the category of "None of the tools we use care about what comes after the 'html' bit of the Doctype, let's just shove our extendo-crap in there"

What you see is not valid DOCTYPE syntax. The formal public identifier follows the `PUBLIC` keyword separated by optional whitespace, not an equals sign. The other examples linked to by the author of the document don't seem to have an equals sign like this one does, but as mentioned it doesn't make any difference anyways.

As for case sensitivity, DOCTYPE declarations are only case-sensitive in XML.

Answer (score 1):

`PUBLIC` does not have a value associated with it, and is part of a **deprecated doctype** according to [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#deprecated-doctype).